# React Native Vertical Sticky Sliding Tab Bar/Panel

Tags: react-native, tabs, expo, react-navigation, vertical-scrolling

I need a way to create a tab bar that will vertically bump up the upper text and stick to the top of the page.

I currently am using createMaterialTopTabNavigator and it sits in the vertical center of the screen. I would like such that when a person scrolls on the subpages from the tab navigator for the whole page to scroll with it until the topTabNavigator sticks to the top of the screen.

I am currently using React Native + Expo.

I am open to different options as well. I have tried using a panel and embedding the tab bar in that but it caused weird scrolling issues on Android devices.

Thanks!